# Blender 3.0 Particle Substeps not working on deformed mesh

Tags: particles

I've noticed particle substeps work by default in 3.0 but not on a mesh being deformed by the armature modifier/mesh cache.

[image]

It seems as if it could be referencing the actual transforms of the mesh, and since its not technically moving it doesnt work?

Or am I hopefully missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: Would u mind provide blend file?

Comment: Sure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_D0H450uPgBwpBvDI9nzO7HzAnR8Ybbb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks. you mean subframes, right? and yes, i could reproduce that behaviour. Might be a limitation or a bug... :(